# grails sort by length

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

Can any body help? I am using hibernate combined with Grails.

I want to execute this sql statement either by findby or createCriteria

```
select user.username, user.email from user where user.username like something order by length(username)
```

The problem occurs for the syntax order by length(username)

I have tried this but get validation sql syntax error:

```
def c = User.createCriteria();
List<User> user = c.list  {
    or {
        ilike("username", search)
        ilike("email", search)
    }

    order(length("username"))
    //order("length(username)")
    //order("username.length()")
    //sqlRestriction("order by length(username)")
}
```

and this

```
List<User> user = User.findAllByUsernameIlikeOrEmailIlike(search, search, [sort: "length(username)"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a criteria query you're out of luck because `order(String propertyName)` cannot access the alias created by `sqlProjection(java.lang.String sql, java.lang.String columnAlias, org.hibernate.type.Type type`). Here's how to project the `username`, `email`, and length of `username`:

```
def rows = User.withCriteria {
    or {
        ilike("username", search)
        ilike("email", search)
    }

    projections {
        property('username')
        property('email')
        sqlProjection('length(username) as usename_len', 'name_len', LONG)
    }
}
```

The criteria query above will return a `List` of `List`, with the inner `List` containing the three columns. However, you cannot sort by `name_len` as part of the query. You'd have to sort the `List` in Groovy:

```
list.sort { it[2] }
// or, and alternative for Groovy >= 2.4.4
list.toSorted { it[2] }
```

## Alternative: HQL

An alternative that can achieve what you're looking for is HQL:

```
def rows = User.executeQuery('SELECT username, email, length(username) as name_len FROM User ORDER BY name_len')
```

The HQL query above not only returns the three columns, it also sorts by `length(username)`. Plus, HQL can *project* the `User` instance itself. In contrast, a criteria query can only project properties. This means that you can get a `List` of sorted `User` instances.

```
def users = User.executeQuery('SELECT u FROM User as u ORDER BY length(username)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way?

```
List<User> users = User.withCriteria {
   or {
       ilike("username", search)
       ilike("email", search)
   }
}.sort { it.username.length }
```

Comment: This add the sort to the list. I want the sort in the sql statement

Comment: It still achieves what you want and reduces and complexity of the query, right?

Comment: no, it doesn't as the importance comes in the sql statement. 

I use dynamic load with help of offset...

Comment: Maybe this clear out what want more
I create a very small load with example max: 3, offset: 0

The where clause is fx. username like 'Dum%'

There is following username is stored in the order as below:
Dummy_101
Dummy_20
Dummy_3
Dummy
Dummy_401

I want to make sure that username Dummy i in first load.

That is why I want the sort on the sql statement

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way...for ascending order

```
 List<User> user = User.findAllByUsernameIlikeOrEmailIlike(username, email).sort{it.username.length}
```

For descending order just change your sort like this

```
 .sort{i1, i2 -> i2.username.length <=> i1.username.length}
```

Comment: This add the sort to the list and not the sql statement. It important that is added to the sql statement